# Create "static" textareas controlled from admin section, how?

Tags: static-website

I'm putting to getter a landing page theme in WP. On the start page of the theme there should be three different boxes of text, where I can describe the product. The thing is that this boxes should be static and not be included in a blog role.

So the most common scenario is that I only add the text once to this three different boxes. Maybe you think now:

- Why don't you just hard code the information in a templete file and add this as the standard showing up when surfing to the site?

And thats a good question, but I wan't to make it more fancy, being able to add OR edit the information in this three boxes from the admin section.

So I thought this could be easily made by "Custom post types". But with this it is just posts/pages under another name, like Movies. And you can add a lot of different movies.

I'm looking for a clean page with three different textareas which control the three different boxes of text on my start page, all done from the admin area. With the ability to edit the text from the same view in the admin section. How can I accomplish this?

/ Fredrik

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved with custom fields, block1, block2, block3. In template (single.php) make three divs, in each set an appropriate meta value (use:  ?php echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'block1', true); ), and then you can control the text within each custom field.

Comment: So fair I'm with you.

But how do I make it appear and be controllable in the admin section?

Answer (score 1):

Or you could add a special 'sidebar' (read: widget area) to your theme that you only show on the main page. Then you can add three 'text' widgets (or even other ones) to that sidebar and with a bit of CSS they'll show next to each other.

see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar
and here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar

Comment: +1 - This was my thought, too. But it wasn't clear to me if the OP wanted different text on different landing pages, or if this was just a one-off. If differing text is desired, then the custom fields answer might be a better fit.

Comment: I usually prefer Widgets since the Custom Field UI is everything but pretty/userfriendly. If you combine it with a plugin like Dynamic Widgets, you can have different text/widgets on different pages.